# jinja2, having trouble with some loops and two table objects

Tags: python, html, loops, jinja2

This is my code:

```html
<!-- Loop thru Table Macro begins-->
{% macro loopThruTable(currentParent, prod)%}
<li> {{prod.category_name}} </li>
{% set currentParent = prod.id %}
{{ checkParent(currentParent) }}
<ul>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    {{ checkParentService(currentParent)}}
</table>
</ul>
    {% endmacro %}
    <!-- Loop thru Table Macro ends-->
    <!-- CheckParent Macro begin-->
    {% macro checkParent(currentParent) %}
    {% for prod in myProd %}
    {% if prod.parent_category_id == currentParent %}
    <ul>
        {{ loopThruTable(currentParent, prod) }}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endmacro %}
    <!-- checkParent Macro Ends-->
    <!-- CheckParentService Macro begin-->
    {% macro checkParentService(currentParent) %}
    {% for serv in myServ %}
    {% if serv.parent_category_id == currentParent %}
    <tr>
        {{ loopThruTableService(currentParent, serv.name) }}
        {{ loopThruTableService(currentParent, serv.price) }}
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
<!-- checkParent Macro Ends-->
<!-- Loop thru Table Macro begins-->
{% macro loopThruTableService(currentParent, blah) %}
<td>{{blah}}</td>
{% endmacro %}
<!-- Loop thru Table Macro ends-->
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}

{% block body %}

<ul>
    {% set parent = 0 %}
    {{ checkParent(parent) }}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

for all intents and purposes it is running *mostly correctly*, but it is adding an extra table at the end of each loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh1o6.png)

as you can see in the bottom, there's a "ServicePrice" that is separating each category.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bATRG.png)

here's another example. I know it has to do with my loops, but as far as jinja2 is concerned, I don't know if there's a method that exists where i check if the parent just 'exists' in my object.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to add one extra for loop and if statement in the loopThruTable Macro.

It now looks like this:

```html
{% macro loopThruTable(currentParent, prod)%}
<li> {{prod.category_name}} </li>
{% set currentParent = prod.id %}
{{ checkParent(currentParent) }}
{% for serv in myServ %}
{% if serv.parent_category_id == currentParent %}
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            {{ checkParentService(currentParent)}}
    </table>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I'm still not entirely sure *why* that works. But it works.